# Parsing multiple json objects and saving them in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have curl command with:

```
 curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
"map":
     {"lat":"123.45543","lon":"45.43424","vibration_level":"456","time_sent":"20.05.1994" } 
}' http://localhost:3000/maps
```

and in my create controller method i have:

```
def create
    @map = Map.new(map_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @map.save
        format.json {
          render :show, status: :created, location: @map
        }
      else
        format.json { render json: @map.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This method was scaffolded. Rails automatically converts my JSON to hash and saves it properly to my db. But how do i parse JSON if I have multiple JSON objects like that:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
"map":
{"lat": "51.088672", "lon": "71.396522", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:00"},
{"lat": "51.088672", "lon": "71.396453", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:01"},
{"lat": "51.088829", "lon": "71.396476", "vibration_level": "300", "time_sent": "07:25:14"} 
}' http://localhost:3000/maps
```

When I try that command, I get a parse error.

EDIT:
maps_controller.rb

```html
class MapsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_map, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :parse_json_data_to_params, except: [ :index,:new,:edit,:show ]

  # GET /maps
  # GET /maps.json
  def index
    @coords = Map.all
  end

  # GET /maps/1
  # GET /maps/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /maps/new
  def new
    @map = Map.new
  end

  # GET /maps/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /maps
  # POST /maps.json
  def create      
    @map = Map.new(map_params)
       respond_to do |format|
      if @map.save
        format.json {
          render :show, status: :created, location: @map
        }
      else
        format.json { render json: @map.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /maps/1
  # PATCH/PUT /maps/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @map.update(map_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @map, notice: 'Map was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @map }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @map.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /maps/1
  # DELETE /maps/1.json
  def destroy
    @map.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to maps_url, notice: 'Map was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_map
      @map = Map.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def map_params
      params.permit(maps: [:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent])
    end

  def parse_json_data_to_params
    params.merge!(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post))
  end

end
```

EDIT 2:

```html
Started POST "/maps" for ::1 at 2015-06-14 20:56:57 +0600
Processing by MapsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"maps"=>[{"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396522", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:00"}, {"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396453", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:01"}, {"lat"=>"51.088829", "lon"=>"71.396476", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:14"}], "map"=>{}}
Unpermitted parameter: map
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 8ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can also simply create them by `@maps = Map.create(map_params)`,  but now - you need to change the definition of `map_params` method, and this is must.

Here is how:

```
def map_params
  params.permit(maps: [:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent])
end
```

And one other thing: Add `attr_accessor: maps` into your model class:

```
def Map < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :maps
  # other code
end
```

**Edit:**

You are passing `"map"=>{}` at the end of JSON, and that's what you are seeing the error for.

Comment: I think that should work, but i get an ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at.

Comment: Can you post the full error and controller's code in you question as an edit?

Comment: When you execute the `curl` command, try it by sending `maps` instead of `map`. Because that's what your controller is expecting.

Comment: I checked my json in jsonlint and found some errors in it. After fixing it and changing map ->maps i have another error. Particularly i have map parameter added somehow to my params. I edited my post.

Comment: @yerassyl That is a feature of Rails. The convention is that the input parameters for create and update actions are wrapped in a top level key whose name is derived from the name of the model corresponding to the controller. Ex : In your `MapsController` the model would be `Map` and the top level key in parameters would be `map`. If this top level key is missing Rails will automatically add it and copy the entire params hash inside that key. You can disable it if you want : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html It is mostly harmless though.

Comment: Hi. I have the exact same problem. I am trying to add multiple hashes to one request. I put the params in square brackets and added a attr_accessor like you suggested but i do also get the 422 error and my parameter log looks like `Parameters: {"{\"user\":"=>{"{\"name\": \"name1\",\"address\": \"addr1\"},{\"name\": \"name2\",\"address\": \"addr2\"}"=>{"}"=>nil}}}` Why are my hashes treated as nil values? I have  constrains on the name and addr and  when i remove them a empty hash gets written. Thanks for reading!